# Jekyll collection not working on github.pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Following the instructions in the Jekyll documention http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/, I created a collection in my jekyll blog for developer related posts

```
collections:
  developer:
    output: true
```

On a jekyll page, I try to output a list of the posts like this

```
  <ul class="posts">
    {% for post in site.developer %}

      <li>
        <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
        <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>

       <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
      </li>

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

This works on my local machine. I can view one post from this collection at

```
http://localhost:4000/developer/2014-07-07-blah-blah.html
```

and a list of the developer posts is visible on the developer page at

```
http://localhost:4000/developer/
```

However, the list isn't visible on github pages and I can't access the post at the url.  The blog otherwise works fine on github pages i.e. all the `site.posts` on the homepage are visible etc.

Note, I did push the files to github. I can see them in the repo.

Comment: Can we see the github repo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that "GitHub Pages" is still using an out-dated version of Jekyll.

GitHub pages' [Dependency versions](https://pages.github.com/versions/) page shows that Jekyll `1.5.1` is used.
But collections feature was introduced in Jekyll 2.0.0 by [PR 2199](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/2199), see Jekyll History page [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#section-5).

If this is the case, then there is nothing you can do, unless you host your repository elsewhere, or push the compiled source to GitHub pages.

Comment: as of 2014 aug 21 jekyll 2.2 is being used. Does that indicate collections can now be used?

Comment: @RyanTuck Yes. It's being used in my Jekyll build right now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Collection to generate custom list for Posts or Pages.

In your front matter add:

```
---
...
flag: dev
---
```

Example for a page list with flag == dev

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {% if page.flag == 'dev' %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But you do for pagination.